# PHP Like button counter in a file.txt

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to recreate several like button that saves count in a file.txt but that doesn't work :/

```
<?php

function getClickCount()
{
    return (int)file_get_contents("counter.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount()
{
    $counter = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter);
}
?>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clicks = 0;

  function onClick() {
    clicks = 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  };

</script>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()" title="Vous aimez la couverture?" class="btn"><img id="heart" src="https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/568304b85fa72dcb958a1edf/584acfc48b82595af77f2030/6257bf1efec79d5baf22309f8f327ce5/favorite.png" /></button>
<p><a id="clicks"><?php echo getClickCount(); ?></a></p>
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wearemaryshair/uhkrzevx/)

Thanks in advance for your help, I am looking since days on the web to find it but I don't...

Alexander

Comment: Use `ajax` to post the clicks to store and get the clicks.

Answer (score 3):

**counter.php**

```
<?php

    function getClickCount() {
        return (int)file_get_contents("counter.txt");
    }

    function incrementClickCount() {
        $counter = getClickCount() + 1;
        file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter);
    }

    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        if($_POST['click'] == 'true') {
            incrementClickCount();
            echo getClickCount();
        } else {
            echo getClickCount();
        }
    }

?>
```

**counter.txt**

```
0
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Click Counter</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button type="button" onClick="onClick()" title="Vous aimez la couverture?" class="btn"><img id="heart" src="https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/568304b85fa72dcb958a1edf/584acfc48b82595af77f2030/6257bf1efec79d5baf22309f8f327ce5/favorite.png" /></button>
      <p><a id="clicks"></a></p>

      <script>
          function onClick() {
              loadClicks(true);
          }

          function loadClicks(isClicked) {
              var click = isClicked === true ? true : false;
              $.ajax({
                 url: 'counter.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                   'click': click
                 },
                 success: function(response) {
                   $('#clicks').text(response);
                 }
              });
          }

          loadClicks(false);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Code Explanation**

Whenever you click the button, there is an `ajax` request sent asynchronously in the background to `counter.php`. This PHP file receives request and process accordingly.

Here in the code, we send a single data to the PHP file in the ajax `POST` request which is a boolean data that is set based on the condition like if the button is clicked.

In PHP file, you will check a condition if the request is happened by button click or else other. If it is by button, you will increment the click and send the click counter value in response else you will only send the value.

You will notice I've called `loadClicks` function with the parameter `true` in `onClick` function and `false` outside the function meaning that I first call the `loadClicks(false)` as soon as the script is started its execution to load only the clicks value and later when I click the button `loadClicks(true)` is invoked meaning increment and fetch the value.

You will understand the code when you go through them carefully.

Comment: Please don't spoil new users by providing them complete code solutions ;-) Better to point them in the right directions, so they can learn. But your solution looks pretty solid. +1 from me.

Comment: I thought he would understand the concept of AJAX by explaining my code itself.

Comment: Nicely structured , pretty elegant flow

Comment: @Novice Thanks friend. :)

Comment: Hey @Perumal93 thank you very much for that code :) i am going to test it right now.

to answer you: I fully understood the way you coded it and what I've missed.Congratulations and again, thank you very much !

Comment: @Perumal93 am I obliged to code it in PHP or can I make it in Javascript? You think this solution is the best? Thank you my friend,

Comment: You can make it with JavaScript. But you cannot store and keep track of counter values once you close the browser or reload the page.  PHP can help you store it in files, database, session and cookie. If you want to make it with JavaScript, there is only one way to do that which is by using cookies. Yes! JavaScript has support to deal with browser cookies. You can store counter values temporarily in cookies and can be tracked. Check out this link. https://js.do/code/js_cookie. I've written a JavaScript code to interaction with browser cookies. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I see 3 problems with your script.

1) You are mixing JavaScript and PHP. JavaScript runs on browsers and PHP runs on servers. If you want to exchange data between those parts of your script you need to make a server call from the JS part to the server, e.g. by using AJAX. A simple HTML request in JavaScript to a PHP script will work too.

2) Also your `<button>` tag needs to be embedded in a `<form>` should point to a script to be executed (can be the same script).

3) You never seem to call `incrementClickCount()`, at least not in the part shown here.

Suggestions

The would code everything in PHP and then address the other two points. Or you need to implement some form of client / server communication.

Comment: Thank you very much Erik for your (so fast) answer. I'll try to make it by myself, I think the solution to implement a form of client / server communication seems to be the best, right?

Comment: `AJAX` is the best solution in your case. If you want me to post the code as an answer, I'll post it.

Comment: Happy to help. AJAX is the most common approach to this kind of problem as @Perumal93 noted.  You can also make server calls in JS yourself with [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

Comment: Waaaw @Perumal93 it would be awesome :) But I still need to understand it to know how to make it in future :) Thank you very much !

Comment: I've posted my code. You could check it out. By the way, I've used jQuery in the code. Let me know if you're comfortable enough with it or not.